# dplyr split by groups and sum

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to sort data by two values (name and p23) then sum similar values of p23. I am still new to dplyr and Im not sure what to do next

```
install.packages("dplyr")
library(dplyr)
# library(tidyr)

df<-data.frame(
  name=c("a","b","b","c","b"),
  p23=c(2,2,3,3,2),
  data=c(0,1,2,3,4)
)
res<-df %>% group_by(name,p23) #now what?
```

Goal

```
a 2 0    #this is also an average but there is only one value
b 2 2.5  #this is the average of the two b's in p23 with value 2
b 3 2
c 3 3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df %>% group_by(name,p23)  %>% summarise(mean(data))
Source: local data frame [4 x 3]
Groups: name

  name p23 mean(data)
1    a   2        0.0
2    b   2        2.5
3    b   3        2.0
4    c   3        3.0
```

Comment: This works, just waiting on the time limit. How would I do this if i had more columns to take the mean of and couldnt list the all by name? eg data and data2

Comment: Just replacing the last piece of code by `summarise(mean(data), mean(data2))`

Comment: Also, `summarise_each(funs(mean),data1,data2)` which retains the columns' original names. @Rilcon42